# Issue with scroll spy and afix

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using the `scrollspy` plugin and `affix` via Bootstrap.

I've set up left sidebar navigation, with menus and submenus and the... spying works fine.

**However, here's the issue:**

- When the page loads, my main menu item "Docs", has the class "active" and is highlighted. As it should
- When the user scrolls down, and the scrollspy (?) plugin takes over, the "Docs" main item is unhighlighted.

**A few notes (even though you can still "view source" in the link):**

- My body tag: `<body data-spy="scroll">`
- My main sidebar tag: `<div class="bs-sidebar hidden-print" role="complementary" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="70" data-offset-bottom="50">`
- I'm also using small script for the smooth-scrolling functionality, but I don't think it affects it.

What's going? Any ideas?

---

**Website:** http://osxpeppermint.com/documentation

Answer (score 1):

> Docs: To easily add scrollspy behavior to your topbar navigation, add
>   data-spy="scroll" to the element you want to spy on (most typically
>   this would be the ). Then add the data-target attribute with the
>   ID or class of the parent element of any Bootstrap .nav component.

```
 <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-example">
```

So you need to decide what nav you are spying on: the side or the top.

This data-target is the .class or #id of the direct parent of the .nav (the wrapper of the nav). See the docs here:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Also, make sure your body has a relative position:

> Requires relative positioning
>
> No matter the implementation method, scrollspy requires the use of
>   position: relative; on the element you're spying on. In most cases
>   this is the .